# How to use in Haskell zipWith correctly to create a [ [ int int ] ] list?

Tags: haskell, zipwith

```
data Tegel = Teg Int Int
type RijTegels = [Tegel]


volleRijTegels :: RijTegels
volleRijTegels = ziptwee [21..36] (replicate 4 1 ++ replicate 4 2 ++ replicate 4 3 ++ replicate 4 4)

ziptwee :: [Int] -> [Int] -> RijTegels
ziptwee []      []    = []
ziptwee (x:xs) (y:ys) = Teg x y: ziptwee xs ys
```

Now I use two functions, but I want to do it with one. 
I thought I could use zipWith, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
volleRijTegels :: RijTegels
volleRijTegels = [zipWith (++) [1,2,3] [4,5,6]] -- here it is going wrong
```

I am placing the outer brackets wrong I guess, but I don't know where they should go.

Anyone who could show me how the work is done?

Comment: your `ziptwee` is already almost the same as `zipWith Teg` - but it won't work because you haven't singled out the case where either input list is empty, just when both are. You need to have `ziptwee [] _ = []` and `ziptwee _ [] = []`, as well as the recursive case.

Comment: `concatMap (replicate 4) [1..4]` or `[1..4] >>= replicate 4` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you want the type `RijTegels` but actually the type you're creating with `zipWith (++)` is `[[a]]`. So to change that you could use the type constructor instead of the `(++)`:

```hs
data Tegel = Teg Int Int deriving (Show)
type RijTegels = [Tegel]

volleRijTegels :: RijTegels
volleRijTegels = zipWith Teg [1,2,3] [4,5,6] -- here it is going wrong

main = print volleRijTegels
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY69CsMwDIR3P4XGFpyhv0MgD9A1LXQwHgwRtlrXDrZJaF/edbyEdhAS3Hd3Mio@0dqcB5UU3FCjhW7ZcHGpzoCBJnIaNlfj5y1L7xGhp0dlY4FFvSRjk7cWV6VtV@xf6@BD452SqVVix/f8IEEc@YmfJTQNGAwIlIAiaL@0z8E7zdhLkSvuMVB57Tc05y8)

Comment: Thank you! So that was what I forgot! Thanks so much :)